# Handling errors in RxJS chain

Tags: rxjs

I have rxjs subject *onEdit$* that emits values. I subscribed to this subject and when value is emitted I call http request to retrieve data.

```
 const onEditSubscription = onEdit$.pipe(
    tap(x => console.log("on Edit")),
    concatMap((data) => this.svc.getAggregate(data as number)),
    retry(),  // <==
).subscribe({
    next : (data) => console.log(data),
    error : (err) => console.log("error")
});
```

I placed `retry` operator to keep subscription active.
Now, when there is `retry` operator if error occurs this.svc.getAggregate that error does not reach subscription (my goal is to let error bubble and be handled by global error handler).
If I remove `retry` then error is logged but subscription to the *onEdit$* subject is canceled.

How to get both things at once, keep subscription alive and allow error to bubble?

Answer (score 0):

onEdit$ will never error, I suppose (looks like an event emitter), so you can just handle errors of the request and return EMPTY to prevent observable from emitting in case of caught error.

```
const onEditSubscription = onEdit$.pipe(
    tap(x => console.log("on Edit")),
    concatMap((data) => this.svc.getAggregate(data as number).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        console?.error(err); // or global err handler
        return EMPTY;
      })
    )),
).subscribe({
    next : (data) => console.log(data)   
});
```